# Can't click controls on my MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing a url on my MPMoviePlayerViewController. And I can't click any controls of the player.

Here's my implementation:

```
  NSURL *streamUrl   = [NSURL URLWithString:movieUrl];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamUrl];
    [[mpvc view] setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:nil];

    mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [mpvc.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [mpvc.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [mpvc.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
    [mpvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [mpvc.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
    [mpvc.moviePlayer setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
```

[MPMoviePlayerViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie69h.png)

Comment: make sure that your code is performed on the main thread

Comment: I am currently calling it in another thread. But now I've placed it in a method. in my main thread and calling in in the other thread. Still having the same result

Comment: not quite clear what you're meaning by the following "But now I've placed it in a method. in my main thread and calling in in the other thread". Is this code actually running on the main thread?

Comment: Before, I am generating my url in a NSOperation and playing it there. Now, I am passing the url that i've generated to a method that I've created. But still I am having the same result

Comment: ))) you still can't answer. does the code run on the main thread or not?

Comment: Fixed it now by adding performSelectorOnMainThread thanks!

Comment: you'e welcome, buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by calling my method with performSelectorOnMainThread